# Non-blocking read on subprocess output without flush() and new line

Tags: python, subprocess, stdout, stdin, nonblocking

I have a program that I can't modify. This program print data to `stdout` WITHOUT flushing it or put `\n` inside and wait for input and so on.

My question is how can I, from a Python script, print in real-time `stdout` and write into his `stdin`? I found some ways to write into his `stdin` without closing the programs but the problem remains for printing his `stdout` too.

In fact, there are some issues with thread, `Popen` and `fcntl` to print in real time his output but they all assumes that the program flush `stdout` after each print and include `\n` in their output.

To be clear, let's say I have a program `test.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (void)
{
    char name[100], age[100], location[100];
    fprintf (stdout, "\nWhat is your name : ");
    fgets (name, sizeof (name), stdin);
    name[strcspn (name, "\n")] = '\0';
    fprintf (stdout, "How old are you : ");
    fgets (age, sizeof (age), stdin);
    age[strcspn (age, "\n")] = '\0';
    fprintf (stdout, "Where do you live : ");
    fgets (location, sizeof (location), stdin);
    location[strcspn (location, "\n")] = '\0';
    fprintf (stdout, "\nHello %s, you have %s years old and live in 
             %s\n\n", name, age, location);
    return 0;
}
```

How can I, from a Python script, output the first `fprintf()` then writing answer into his stdin and so on in the same way I could simply launch `test.c`?

The purpose is to control data sent to this program from a script and still having return on what happens.

Comment: This goes into the bad lands of non-portability (at least possibly so). On what OSes do you need your code to run.

Comment: Sorry, this is for Linux

Answer (score 0):

You may use the following program which is heavily relying on the `subprocess` package from the standard Python language:

```
def run_program(cmd, sinput=''):
    """Run the command line and output (ret, sout, serr)."""
    import subprocess

    proc =  subprocess.Popen(cmd,
                             stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                             stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                             stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    sin = proc.stdin
    sout, serr = proc.communicate(sinput.encode("utf-8"))
    ret = proc.wait()

    return (ret, sout, serr)
```

So, the program you just wrote in C would give the following:

```
cmd = ['myprogram']
sinput = 'myname\n6\nWhitechapel\n'
(ret, sout, serr) = run_program(cmd, sinput)
```

Note that you cannot avoid the `\n` character simply because it is used by your target program to know that you send the answer to a question.

Comment: I would imagine that it is possible, using `pty`(and maybe `tty`). Since the normal terminal can do it, so should Python, given that the correct `termios` settings.

Comment: Correct, but overkilling in term of complexity (you would have to look for the proper `pty`/`tty` to link to your process). Don't you think ?

Comment: No, you would have Python create a new pty, using something from the `pty` module, e.g. `pty.openpty()`. But then you need to fix the terminal settings. And, as I am not linux currently, I cannot test it and get it to work correctly.